# Which is the common-average buffer size for InternetReadFile?

Tags: delphi, download, size, buffer, wininet

I use WinInet.h in Delphi to download files over HTTP with the average size between 30 KB and 1.5 MB.

```
var
  Buf: array[0..BUFFER_SIZE - 1] of Byte;
while BOOL(InternetReadFile(hUrl, @Buf, SizeOf(Buf), BytesRead)) and (BytesRead > 0) do
 if Terminated then
   Exit
 else
 begin
   FStream.WriteBuffer(Buf, BytesRead);
   Synchronize(UpdateProgress);
   FillChar(Buf, SizeOf(Buf), 0);
 end;
```

What is the recommended buffer size for such downloads - if shouldn't be too big neither too small.

Comment: Use Indy (IdHTTP.pas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such buffers, I usualy code:

```
var
  Buf: array[word] of byte;
```

Which allocates 64 KB of buffer.

But, from my little experiment, *WinINet* is so slow that the internal buffer size won't change much.

If you look for performance, take a look at *WinHTTP*, which is much faster than *WinINet*. More than 10 times faster, at least for multiple connections. Only missing feature is the dialog boxes for remote dial-up access:

> *Microsoft Windows HTTP Services (WinHTTP) provides developers with a
>   server-supported, high-level interface
>   to the HTTP/1.1 Internet protocol.
>   WinHTTP is designed to be used
>   primarily in server-based scenarios by
>   server applications that communicate
>   with HTTP servers.*
>
> *WinINet was designed as an HTTP client platform for interactive
>   desktop applications, such as
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer, Microsoft
>   Office, and Microsoft Money. WinINet
>   displays a user interface for some
>   operations such as collecting user
>   credentials. WinHTTP, however, handles
>   these operations programmatically.
>   Server applications that require HTTP
>   client services should use WinHTTP
>   instead of WinINet. For more
>   information, see Porting WinINet
>   Applications to WinHTTP.*
>
> *WinHTTP is also designed for use in system services and HTTP-based client
>   applications. However, single-user
>   applications that require FTP protocol
>   functionality, cookie persistence,
>   caching, automatic credential dialog
>   handling, Internet Explorer
>   compatibility, or downlevel platform
>   support should consider using
>   WinINet.*
>
> Extracted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I've implemented both WinInet and WinHTTP client access in our Open Source ORM framework. You may take a look at this blog article to find out [more info about *WinHTTP*](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/04/WinINet-vs-WinHTTP).

As far as I know, the latest version of IE uses *WinHTTP* instead of *WinINet*. So we may consider going in the same direction.

Comment: Link is broken!

Comment: updated link: https://blog.synopse.info/?post/2011/07/04/WinINet-vs-WinHTTP

Comment: Can you please confirm that the function that implements the WinHTTP function (for downloading a file, for example) is TSQLHttpClientWinSock.InternalRequest ? Thanks. It would be nice if the function could be somehow separated in a single file....

Comment: Update: I just discovered that the Indy "download file" function (IdHTTP.pas) is a much better separated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant difference, but i think that best value is 65 536 bytes (tcp limit for package), or 30 000 bytes because your smallest files less of 65 536.

Comment: Agreed, programmers tend to like to pull powers of 2 out of their hats. Given the large size of disk caches, I usually go for 128K or 256K, but unless you actually test it with a local http server, and a code profiler, it's likely impossible to tell the difference.